# Scons: How to add a target for creating a zip file that contains source files?

Tags: build, scons

Say I have a couple of source files (e.g.`foo.c`, `foo.h`, `bar.c`, `bar.h`, `baz.c`, `baz.h`). I want to bundle them together by making a zip file that contains those files by simply typing `scons zip`. In addition, those files have to be inside a `src/` directory in the zip file.

How should I proceed? I've looked at the `Mkdir()`, `Copy()` etc. commands in the Scons user manual, but I have no idea how to bundle them together in a single target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a very simple **SConstruct** to do what you want. You'll have to modify it for your real source layout and you probably don't want to create a `src/` directory at the root of your project.

```
# list of source, header files
files = ['foo.h', 'foo.c', 'bar.h', 'bar.c', 'baz.h', 'baz.c']

# create the directory structure for the zip file
pkg_files = Install('src', files)

# create the zip file
z = Zip('pkg.zip', pkg_files)
Alias('zip', z)
```

You can find more information about the Zip Builder on the [SCons man page](http://www.scons.org/doc/HTML/scons-man.html).